# sending chunks of data from client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

I am using sockets to send a file. On the server side I am listening to stream from the client side, but from the client side, I am not able to send data in chunks which can be sent to the server side.
I used FileReader to read the file in slices can you please tell what is that I am doing wrong?

Client Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Echo server</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form id="form" id="chat_form">
        <input type="file" id="file_input" />
        <input type="button" onclick="submit1()" value="submit">
    </form>
    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = io('localhost:8080');
        var fReader;
        socket.on('echo', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        socket.emit('echo', 'this is a message');
        function submit1() {
            var file = $("#file_input")[0].files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (evnt) {
                socket.emit('join', { 'Name': Name, Data: evnt.target.result });
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</head>
```

SERVER code

```
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express')
var socketio = require('socket.io')
var app = express(server)
var server = http.Server(app)
var io = socketio(server)

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client.html')
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  var writeStream  = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname +'/m.png');
  socket.on('echo', function(data){
    socket.emit('echo', data);
  });
  socket.on('join', function(chunk){
    console.log(chunk, "==============chunk=====================");
    writeStream.write(chunk);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You never give the `file` object to your `FileReader` object.  In fact, you never do anything with it so the `FileReader` object never has anything to do.  For example, you may want to do:

```
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

It also doesn't look like you're getting the data from the reader object correctly.  There's a code examples here: [File upload with socket.io](https://medium.com/@Mewsse/file-upload-with-socket-io-9d2d1229494) and [Send Images through Websockets](http://blog.marcon.me/post/31143865164/send-images-through-websockets).

Comment: I did that and still, I am not able to send large files and browser crashes but I am able to send small files correctly @jfriend00

Comment: @aryankanwar - Then follow the example I linked and send the file in manageable chunks.  How big is the file?  Or send it with HTTP uploads which is built for any size.